# how dynamically set the background picture in oracle ADF?

Tags: oracle-adf

in oracle `adf` I have a login page with a background picture. I fixed the picture size, now in different monitor with different resolution, picture display with it's fixed size.
I want to know how set the picture that dynamically match the size of monitor?

Answer (score 0):

What JDev version do you use?
Can't you solve this by using CSS? Since I guess your login page is just a plain .html page.